# Mutating Trigger - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Another one of those mutating trigger errors without an idea of how to fix it. The function counts the number of reviews given and the trigger displays the number of review records:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_no_of_reviews_for_venue (in_venue_id reviews.venue_id%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
    vn_no_of_reviews reviews.review_id%TYPE := 0;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO vn_no_of_reviews
    FROM reviews;

    RETURN vn_no_of_reviews;
END func_no_of_reviews_for_venue;
/
SHOW ERRORS;

-- trigger to get a venue's average rating when a new review has been added
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_get_venue_avg_rating
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF rating ON reviews
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.rating IS NOT NULL)

DECLARE
    vn_no_reviews NUMBER(6);
    vn_avg NUMBER(2,1);
BEGIN 

    vn_no_reviews := func_no_of_reviews_for_venue(:NEW.venue_id);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Number of reviews: ' || vn_no_reviews);

END trig_age_ck;
/
```

Comment: you are not allowed to select from the same table you are firing the trigger on.

Comment: That makes sense, will I even be able to do this logically? I'm trying to get the number of reviews, unless I trigger it when a venue's information has been updated...

Comment: Why are you trying to get the number of reviews and what are you going to do with that information?  Presumably, you're not really using `dbms_output` in production code.  If you want a count, you'd generally do that as an additional step either before or after inserting the new row(s) depending on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to get the average rating for a venue by counting the total of reviews and the total of all the review ratings

Comment: @JustinCave I've managed to get the query counting the total number of VARRAY items but by changing the type from AFTER to BEFORE it's always one step behind, but I suppose at least that doesn't cause a mutating error

Comment: If you insist on using a trigger (this is not a problem that using a trigger is appropriate), to do it correctly, you'd need a before statement trigger, a row-level trigger, and an after statement trigger.  The before statement would initialize a collection in a package.  The row-level trigger adds the `venue_id` to the collection.  And the after statement trigger iterates through the collection and queries the table.  But you really don't want to solve this through a trigger.